# If a thread gets interrupted on wait(), will the monitor be re-acquired before reaching the catch block outside of the synchronization block?

Tags: java, multithreading, try-catch, monitor, interrupted-exception

Please consider the following code:

```
try{
    synchronized(myLock){
        myLock.wait(); // gets interrupted while waiting.
   }
}catch(InterruptedException ie){

}
```

If a thread gets interrupted while blocked on wait(), will the monitor of myLock be re-acquired (temporarily?) before ended up in the catch block?

Comment: What do you mean by "interrupted?"

Comment: Like calling thread.interrupt(). I do not understand. What is the ambiguity about "interrupted"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) states

> If the current thread is interrupted by any thread before or while it
>   is waiting, then an InterruptedException is thrown. This exception is
>   not thrown until the lock status of this object has been restored as
>   described above.

So, yes, it will be blocked waiting for the lock to be reacquired and then throw the exception.